# Delphi XE3, ugly StringGrid's borders

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7, delphi-xe3

Why StringGrid's borders are so unclear in XE3, comparing to Delphi7? How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: The control is themed in XE3. In my opinion, this is a major improvement. The D7 unthemed style looks very wrong in a themed desktop environment.

Comment: I can imagine why darker borders would seem more clear; it seperates the data better. Nevertheless there's a reason why modern programs remove these lines or make them much lighter. It's because our brain is very good in recognising the columns just by alignment of the text. That's why there are no such borders between text columns either. You don't need them.

Comment: Nevertheless one wonders why the outer border of a listview for instance is considerably darker than that of a stringgrid when both controls are themed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After Delphi 2010 all the Grids are themed. To disable the new theme on a grid you have to set the property 
DrawingStyle to gdsClassic in the objects inspector.